# Why isn't this showing?

Tags: jquery

Web Developer is showing my JavaScript as being valid, but if I run the page this does not work. I tried following the usage on jquery-color's site, but it kept returning property id missing everytime. I really wish when I took JavaScript in college that I had a better instructor. He flashed through jQuery and most of JavaScript as a whole without really teaching it.

Edit #1: I fixed the (this) error in the code, but still a no go.

Here is the code for the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery("li.site-links").hover(function(){
            jQuery(this).stop().animate({
                backgroundColor: "#000000"
            }, 1000 );
        });
    </script>
```

and site link: http://lab.nmjgraphics.com

Comment: You can't animate colors with jQuery unless you include a plugin for that.

Comment: I do have the jquery-color plugin and it is loaded after the jquery.

Comment: Please don't fix the code in your question. It invalidates the answers, and it makes the question useless for anyone to come.

Comment: sorry wasn't aware of that, first time ever asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery("a.site-links").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('li').stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "#000000"
        }, 1000 );
    },function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('li').stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "transparent"
    }, 1000 );
    });
 });
```

You can either try with `.parent('li')`

or try this:

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery("a.site-links").parent('li').hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "#000000"
        }, 1000 );
    },function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('li').stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "transparent"
    }, 1000 );
    });
 });
```

Comment: If I do that I get the following:

`Timestamp: 1/30/2013 1:53:30 AM
Error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id
Source File: http://lab.nmjgraphics.com/
Line: 36, Column: 10
Source Code:
    jQuery("li.site-links").hover(function(){ `

Comment: updated the answer, I hope you are using jquery ui for color animation.

Comment: I am using jquery-color plugin. I was researching on here and everything pointed to that plugin.

Comment: That worked perfect. I am going to study that little guy, now the fun part, gotta get it back to the original color lol.

Comment: use a callback function to get the original color.

Comment: I will look into it tomorrow after I get out of class and work. My marathon is over lol. I have been coding away on this and another project for almost 70 hours with 3 hour nap breaks.

Comment: Wow thank you, man I might actually get more than 3 hours rest tonight lol. Thank you again for posting the complete script with the mouse out. I will study it the next couple of days and see what I have been doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change `"this"` to `this` in the selector to access the source of event. Use "this" in selector will search for tag names this, like `jQuery("input")` will get all tags with name `input`.

Change

```
 jQuery("this")
```

To

```
 jQuery(this)
```

You can check the difference between `"this"` to `this` over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/T8NU2/1/)

Comment: This is a second question that introduces `$("this")`. Any idea where that came from?

Comment: yeah that would help (surprised it didn't kick a error on that), but still not working.

Comment: @NathanJ2012 `$("this")` is a valid selector that selects all elements with the tag name "`this`".

Answer (score 0):

First: your selector is wrong. You don't have `<a>` with .site-link. You have `<li><a>` with a .site-link

Therefore:

```
$(".site-links").hover(function(){
jQuery(this).parent().stop().animate({
    backgroundColor: "#000"
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Here is a demo with  opacity:
http://jsfiddle.net/2VgBa/

Comment: jQuery can animate colors with an appropriate plugin installed. OP has that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `$("this")` to `$(this)` fix,

`jQuery("li.site-links")` looks for a `li` with the class `site-links`, but there are none on your live site, so *this* selector does not select anything.

To fix this, any of these will work

- change the selector to `"li .site-links"` to target any `.site-links` within any `li`, or
- add the `site-links` class to the `li` (`<li class="site-links">`), or
- change the selector to `"a.site-links` to target any `a` with the class `site-links`.

---

Also, you try to animate the background color to black on every hover, but you never undo the animation. Is that what you want? Perhaps you want something like

```
jQuery("li.site-links").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "rgb(79, 89, 100)"
    }, 1000 );
},function(){
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
        // color alpha not supported in IE8: http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba
        backgroundColor: "rgba(79, 89, 100, 0)"
    }, 1000 );
});
```

---

If reduced experience in IE<10 (no animation, background changes abruptly) is not an issue, you should use CSS transitions as they can transition any kind of background (not just colors) and no javascript is needed:

```
#menu-bar li{
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  background: url("../imgs/menu-normal.png");
}

#menu-bar li:hover{
  background: url("../imgs/menu-hover.png");
}
```

Comment: The idea is a mouse over event so when you move over the li the background changes to #4f5964 and then back to normal when the mouse moves out. I used black because it is easier to hit 0 six times lol. I was following the usage guide on jquery-color's github page with not much success.

Comment: and I am officially tired. I meant to put in #menu-bar li

Comment: @NathanJ2012 while you can animate colors with a plugin, that plugin won't affect gradients (and I don't know if it can handle transparency). You should look into CSS transitions, if reduced quality is not an issue in OldIE.

Comment: I am aiming for as much cross-browser compatibility as possible. I am using a solid color for this effect and not the gradients I commented out in the menu css.

Comment: other problem is everytime I try to work with jQuery I find a css alternative, and I am not going to learn by running back to CSS everytime :\

Comment: @NathanJ2012 sorry; didn't know this was meant as an excercise in javascript. However, what I've said still applies: jQuery is unable to transition gradient backgrounds and you'll have to resort to opacity / rgba colors, and you never animate back from black.

Comment: what if that gradient was a background instead of a css?

I don't really like using the css gradient anyways.

Comment: @NathanJ2012 you can transition images and background opacity in CSS as well, not just colors.